# File Client: Permissions?

Tags: ftp, ssl, sftp, filezilla

So on a linux server, I was recently made as an admin, and I have writing rights to manage and write data on the server. However, I have to `sudo su` in order to do this.

When I try to use an FTP client (such as Filezilla), it is not recognizing that I have writing rights, and any directory uploads I try to push up is denied. When I had to push a single file up, it accepted.

I tried changing the directory permissions to 775, and had nothing come out of it.

Thank you! Any help is appreciated!

Edit: (Originally on stackoverflow before Kenster pointed me this direction.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your FTP user is by itself not root. The FTP server does not know that you have permission to do this, and the FTP protocol doesn't have a mechanism for sending an `su` request.

A workaround is to upload the folder with your normal user, but to your users home directory. Then you shell in and `sudo su`, and then copy the folder to where you actually want it. Be sure to `chown` the folder to the correct owner afterwards, tho.

Your approach of changing the permission to `775` could work, provided that your user is the same group as whoever owns the folder you're uploading to.

---

PS: Because of safety and security, you generally don't want to allow people to log in as root directly, be it via FTP or SSH.

Comment: That makes sense as to why I have my own user directory. I could not understand that until you explained something. I'll give it a shot and report back. :) Thanks!

Comment: @Techgirl-52 Basically, it goes like this: Everyone has their own user. In addition, there is the root-user that has all rights. Some users are allowed so `sudo su` to become root.